# Wordpress - Lunch Menu Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I've been looking for a lunch menu plugin that would accomplish the below but haven't found one and I've also been brainstorming ways in which I could go around having the steps done but still no luck so if anyone knows a plugin or any innovative way to accomplish what I have below then please share. Thanks.

The idea of how I would like the lunch menu to work (It's for internal ordering of lunch within a company who currently calls the front desk to order or leave their desk to write their order in the lunch book. We also have 2 vendors from who we order lunch from where both have changing menus on a daily basis)

1. In the backend of the website there would be a section where the admin/lunch person can enter all the possible lunch orders like fry chicken, curry goat, etc. This would be just to have a premade list of all the food both vendors offer. (I guess each food would be categorized under Vendor 1 or Vendor 2).
2. From that premade list, the admin/lunch person can go on the LUNCH PAGE and for each day of the week just add the respective lunch items under that day from the premade list without having to type it.
3. After updating the LUNCH PAGE, the users/employees can login to the intranet and head over to the LUNCH PAGE on the frontend, tick/select from the lunch menu what they want for the current&/future day(s) and from there just click submit and then it will be emailed to the admin/lunch person to make the order for them. That way they won't have to be calling the front desk constantly.

I hope this isn't confusing. Please let me know if there is anything you would like to know. Meanwhile amma go brainstorm other ways to get this to how I want it.

Thanks
~ Adrian

Comment: do you have a design you can show us?

Comment: in terms of how it would work?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: No the display would be just a simple list with the Day being the header and the items listing down .
How it would work is:
1. The lunch menu plugin would possibly have a custom post type.
2. The categories for the post type would be used as the different vendors.
3. Then each lunch item created like a post itself within the post type and assigned to their respective vendor.
4. The lunch page would be designed as needed with the respective days.

Comment: 5. And from there myself/the lunch person can just select from the post type the different lunch items and add it to the editor? If that makes sense.

Sorry I'm still trying to figure out how exactly it would be done but something to that sense.

Comment: Now am even thinking if some sort of contact form could accomplish this since I need the email feature. My main concern is having that premade list so she doesn't have to be typing items over every time.